# Newbie question regarding JS and Listing Distributions

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

In this case I am not sure from where to even start properly, but the task is to use javascript to list the distributions. I was thinking that the script should start with `var AWS = require("aws-sdk");` which should get the aws-sdk and from it use the values that I need which is to match X domain and get the DistributionID for that domain but still not sure. Below is a code of what I am executing in bash which provides me with the exact info that I have, but I need to somehow convert the call in javascript.

```
aws cloudfront list-distributions --profile=my profile name --query "DistributionList.Items[?Aliases.Items!=null] | [?contains(Aliases.Items, 'Specific-Domain.com')].Id" > Id-Output.txt
```

The output of the code above is the required Id which afterwards can be used for a lot of things including invalidation, but as for converting it to a JavaScript I am little over my head, so please be gentle and thanks for stopping by (or providing me with any suggestion or info).

Comment: Note, `Java` and `JavaScript` are completely separate programming languages with no relation to each other, besides the similar name.

Answer (score 0):

In the CLI you are using the `list-distributions` method of the `cloudfront` service. Similarly, you would use the `listDistributions` method of the `AWS.CloudFront` client in the AWS SDK for JavaScript to perform the same task, as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFront.html#listDistributions-property).

Comment: I have double checked the documentation in question but I simply could not figure how to start the coding, any Examples how it should look are welcome.

Comment: There's literally an example at the page I linked. Where are you stuck exactly? You need to show some sort of effort and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I am not sure what exactly should be placed in the var paramaters. At the moment I think it should have `CNAME: ''` and then maybe `ifMatch: 'example-domain.com` get the DistributionId of that domain and set it as variable. Not sure   learning it in process ...

Comment: `var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var cloudfront = new AWS.CloudFront();
var params = {
//Marker      : 'STRING_VALUE',
//MaxItems    : 'STRING_VALUE',
//Id : 'STRING_VALUE',
CNAME       : '', 
IfMatch     : 'example-domain.com'/* Domain Required */
};
cloudfront.listDistributions(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error
  else     console.log(data);           // successful
});`
From the reading material that you provided I found the code as you  mentioned and shown above, but I am not sure how to do the rest still reading from it but...

Comment: Trying to figure out how after the cloudfront.listDistributions to match the CNAME / search for specific domain in the CNAME value and once it finds it in the output to grab it's DistributionId. Still Reading the massive documentation but nothing comes to mind. Will not stop trying.